# How to append in an array mongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, append

How can i append something in an array after i search a specific object, Database looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608a0f3628588a3daca019c6"
    },
    "username": "paul",
    "password": "cacavaca",
    "question": "q1",
    "answer": "cutu",
    "friends": [mir],
    "groups": []
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "608a0f4328588a3daca019c7"
    },
    "username": "mir",
    "password": "123456",
    "question": "q1",
    "answer": "cutu",
    "friends": [],
    "groups": []
}
```

I want to search the object by **username: paul** and append **alex** in the friends array, i have tried this but its not wokring:

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        var dbc = db.db("chat");
        dbc.collection("accounts").find({username: { $eq: user}}).update( [
            {
              $push: {
                friends:alex
              }
            }

        ])
        db.close();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of use `.find()` method, you should use `updateOne()` like this :

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    var dbc = db.db("chat");
    dbc.collection("accounts").updateOne({username: {$eq: user}}, {
       $push: {
           friends: alex
        }
    });
    db.close();
});
```

Supposing `user` and `alex` are variables defined above.

Also, maybe you can only write `{username: user}` without `$eq` but it depends your code and logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
var user = request.body.user;
var new_friend = request.body.new_friend;

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
        var dbc = db.db("chat");
        dbc.collection("accounts").update(
        {username: { $eq: user}},
            {
              $push: {
                friends:new_friend
              }
            }
        )
        db.close();
    });
```